# How to automatically increase scrapy's DOWNLOAD_DELAY while detecting code 500 in response's status

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, delay

I am going to write hundreds of spiders to crawl different static web pages, so I choose Scrapy to help me to finish my work.

During the work, I find most of the websites are simple and do not anti spiders. But I found it difficult to set a suit `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` in `scrapy.setting.py` file. There are too many spiders to code and find a suitable `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` for each spider will run me out of time.

I want to know which models of scrapy load and use `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` parameter, and how to code a program to automatically increase `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` while detecting serve error (the spider requests too frequent).

Comment: If your crawlers are strong enough to hug a website to death you should probably start with a more reasonable delay to begin with :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `AutoThrottle` middleware that is responsible for managing delays with your own policy:

```
# extensions.py

from scrapy.extensions.throttle import AutoThrottle

class ZombieThrottle(AutoThrottle):
    """start throttling when web page dies"""

    def _adjust_delay(self, slot, latency, response):
        """Define delay adjustment policy"""
        if response.status == 500:
            slot.delay = 60  # 1 minute
```

And enable it instead of default one in your `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle': None,
    'myspider.extensions.ZombieThrottle': 0,
}
```

Comment: Love it, clean solution.